# Awkward data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I am writing a utility that takes tab delimited text files and outputs HTML tables.  Part of the functionality is the ability to pass filter values at the command prompt.  So, for example, if we have a column "A" I should be able to pass --filter "A" "foo" and see only rows for which the column "A" contained "foo."

This brings me to my question.  I'm writing this in C, and perhaps due to my inexperience with the language, I'm having trouble expressing my "filter" data structure.

My initial stab at the problem is to store the filters upfront:

```
//Parse parameters and values, i.e. --start, --length
for (; i<argc; i++){
    if (argv[i][1] == '-'){
        argv[i]++; //Strip long options 
        if (i+1 == argc || argv[i+1][0] == '-'){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Missing argument to optional parameter!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-start")==0)
        start = strtol(argv[i+1], NULL, 0);
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-length")==0)
        length = strtol(argv[i+1], NULL, 0);
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-filter")==0){ //Store the filter arguments for later processing
        filters = realloc(filters, sizeof(char*) * (f+2));
        filters[f++] = strdup(argv[i+1]);
        filters[f++] = strdup(argv[i+2]);
    }
}
```

And then, once I have the column names, to create a sparsely populated array of filter values that corresponds to the length of the file header.  So, if I'm looking at column 4, I look up the fourth value of the filter array and check if it is populated with a value.

The code that expands the "initial" storage of the filter into this lookup table is as follows:

```
//Now that we know how many cols we have, create a sparsely populated filter array
for (j=0,i=0; i<ncols; i++){
    filtercols = realloc(filtercols, sizeof(char*) * (ncols+1));
    filtercols[i] = strdup("");
    for (c=0; c<f; c++){
        if (strcmp(columns + j, filters[c])==0){
            filtercols[i] = strdup(filters[c+1]);
            break;
        }
    }

    while (columns[j]){
        j++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

Other than being awkward, I can see that if I specify a filter that has the same value for both the column name and the filter value, this won't work.

In something like Python, I'd handle this with dictionaries.  What is the best idiom available for this situation when working in C?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not an answer to the actual problem but I think you should use POSIX compliant `getopt()` or `getopt_long()` functions for proper (and easier) argument handling.

Small guidebook here: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Comment: Be advised that the `strtol` function needs the numeric base of the desired output as its third argument, so I recommend `length = strtol(argv[i+1], NULL, 10);`

Comment: Yikes! Why `realloc` in every iteration of the loop? You can almost always do better than that. Do you need to know how to implement a dynamic array in c?

Comment: @dmckee, the loop is likely to be very short as it is parsing arguments, but point well taken.  by dynamic array do you mean allocing more than needed ahead of time and doubling when needed?

Comment: @Athabaska Dick, the code is modeled after what I saw in the open source code of the sqlite3 shell utility.  Can getopt be used on Windows without much trouble?

Comment: @zchtodd If you are using MinGW / GCC there are no problems at all. With MSVC its more problematic since it doesnt follow posix or any other proper standard.

Comment: @zchtodd: Yep. Though the factor doesn't have to be two. But if you're processing arguments just allocate it to length `argc` in the first place. You might waste a little, but who cares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a hash:

http://uthash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is an obvious solution as hashmaps are often the data structure that underlie associative arrays like python's dictionary.

Comment: I've decided to go with my original code, awkward as it is.  Incorporating an outside library that is probably more code than the utility itself seems like overkill.  uthash is definitely very interesting, though.